# What about bean-validation's date constraints and java.time?

Tags: bean-validation, java-8, java-time

Bean Validation comes with those built-ins [`@Past`](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#d0e9529) and [`@Future`](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#d0e9534). According to the specification those constraints are only supporting those old `Date` and `Calendar` classes. What are my options for using those Bean Validation built-ins with java.time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better place for asking this question would be the [beanvalidation-dev List](https://lists.jboss.org/mailman/listinfo/beanvalidation-dev). Fortunately [I did recently](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/beanvalidation-dev/2014-March/000963.html):

> Supporting new Java 8 data types seems to be a good candidate for 
>   the next iteration of the Bean Validation spec. [..] However, in Hibenrate Validator
>   we already started the work on [supporting Java 8](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-825), including the [new date and time types](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-874).
>   Hibernate Validator 5.2 should make this functionality available, probably well before there will be a new spec version.

That will be the following options for you:

- Wait for HV 5.2
- Implement own validators and [add these to the built-ins](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#xml-mapping-constraintdefinition).
- Use a [third party library](https://github.com/malkusch/validation) which supplies validators for those built-ins.

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm the author of that library.</sub>